# Georeferencing CAD Causing Close Out/Shut Down of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, cad

I am currently running ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

I have no other georeferencing issues regarding TIFFs shapefiles, or otherwise.

However, when I introduce a CAD (or DWG) file into the map and attempt to georeference the file with links, ArcMap immediately freezes for a moment and closes out.

If I move the CAD file using shift or scale, there are no issues, only when I attempt to use links.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution that worked for me is creating CAD world file manually. It is simple, all you need is a pair of coordinates for 2 points in opposite corners. Fromx fromy tox toy, same for 2nd corner

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/de/desktop/latest/manage-data/cad/world-files-for-cad-datasets.htm

Answer (score -2):

follow this link it is helpful
http://www.tzgis.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-avoid-arcgis-crashing-during.html

Comment: In order to avoid the perils of link-rot, can you post the relevant details from that link in your answer?