# Using Spatial Adjustment to georeference shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, spatial-adjustment

I am having trouble using spatial adjustment to georeference a shapefile that I created from a CAD drawing to a basemap of satellite imagery.

At first, the shapefile had an unknown coordinate system, and I created about 10 displacement links and the adjust option was still greyed out in the drop-down menu.

I tried defining the projection of the shapefile to NAD 83 UTM Zone 17N, because I would need it in that projection eventually, but the adjust option is still greyed out.

It seems that I can't get the option no matter how many displacement links I add as well.

Am I missing something?

Comment: CAD using only 2 points. Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108940/georeferencing-cad-causing-close-out-shut-down-of-arcmap

Comment: Are you in an edit session?

Comment: @Jyler Yes, I am in an edit session.

Comment: @FelixIP Thank you for the link, but I would also like to figure out why I can't spatially adjust it in shapefile format, if possible.

Comment: You have to check one in adjustment dialog. Set Adjusted data

Answer (score 1):

Had to either select all features or go into Select Adjust Data... and choose the All Features in These Layers: option.